# The number of people in an audthorium is between 80 and 100, knowimg that the number of men is 7/8 the number of women, what is the number of people?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

I would like some help solving that problem.
My approach: I've shown that x is between 128/3 and 160/3 but that didn't help me and now I'm stuck. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: the number is an integer

Comment: Yeah I know, but thing is there's many integers between 128/3 and 160/3, how can i know the correct one knowing that 7/8x also must be an integer?

Comment: I would suggest that you step back and try to get some insight beyond your first thought. You will do better to solve this yourself - it will feed your mathematical imagination - than have me solve it: for me the solution is obvious, pretty much by inspection, and you will get more surely to the point where it is obvious to you in another similar question if you do the thinking yourself. Have you used all the information you have been given?

Comment: Yeah I think I've used all of the given information

Comment: @Pritchard: I assume $x$ is the number of women. Since you found that that number is between 43 and 53, you need to pick one that is divisible by 8 because the number of men is a whole number

Comment: Ah, i see, so the answer is 48( the number of women) and 42 (the number of men) which in total is 90 people, thanks you very much for the help

Comment: @Pritchard: Yes! Since both $x$ and $\frac{7}{8}x$ have to be whole numbers

Comment: Again thank you very much pal

Answer (score 0):

The total number of people is the number of women plus $7/8$ the number of women.

\begin{align*}
m&=\dfrac{7w}{8}\\
\implies w+\dfrac{7w}{8}&=total\\
\implies8w+7m&=15\\
\implies16w+14m&=20\\
\implies24w+21m&=45\\
\implies32w+26m&=60\\
\implies40w+35m&=75\\
\implies48w+42m&=90\\
\end{align*}

It appears that your $\quad x=48=\dfrac{144}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. $7+8=15$, so out of every $15$ people, seven are men, and eight are women. $90$ is six fifteens (five fifteens is only $75$ people, too few, and seven fifteens is $105$ people, too many), so $6\times7$ men, and $6\times8$ women.